# Can’t choose enchantments

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In *Minecraft: Pocket Edition*, I can't see what each enchantment is. I can enchant but I can't see what the individual enchantments are, so if the level 1 enchantment is better I would not know.

My brother is also on Pocket Edition but he has a separate button to finalize the enchantment. Can I add this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to know what the enchantment is until after you have finalized it in vanilla minecraft. It is possible to change this using addons and/or mods, however.

Comment: That’s weird since for my brother there is a separate button to finalize and on computer you can see the enchantment by hovering the mouse over.

Comment: Again, it is possible to get mods and addons to allow that. That is the only way to know what the enchantment is before you finalize it. The thing that you see when you hover over it is a possible enchantment, but this only works in Java

Comment: Well, he says he has no mods or anything and he is also on an IOS device, same version of Minecraft. Guess I’ll just have to live with it.

Comment: @Ben602 if this answer solved your question, you should consider check this answer as the [accepted answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).